# Creating new record automagically fills the type column with the class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am new to rails and investigating a code that I inherited I see in file **task.rb** this:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord

  include ActiveRecord::UnionScope

  default_scope { where.not(status: 'Canceled') }
  scope :done, -> { where(status: 'Done').order(id: :desc) }
  scope :pending, -> { where(status: 'Pending').order(id: :desc) }
  scope :in_progress, -> { where.not(status: 'Done').order(id: :asc) }

  def type_human_readable
    self.class.to_s
  end

end

class SwitchDbConfigFiles < Task
  def type_human_readable
    'Switch Database Configuration Files'
  end
end
```

where:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

When I enter the rails console and create a new task like this:

> Task::SwitchDbConfigFiles.create!({date: Time.now}

[image]

I looked into the shcema but didn't find anything about the `type` column

```
  create_table "tasks", id: :integer, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string "type"
    t.date "date"
    t.text "message"
    t.string "status", default: "Pending", null: false
    t.text "data"
    t.index ["date", "status", "type"], name: "last_task_of_type_3"
    t.index ["date", "type", "status"], name: "last_task_of_type_2"
    t.index ["type", "status", "date"], name: "last_task_of_type"
  end
```

The question is: How on earth(by what rule) the type column is being assigned the model-class-name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like ActiveRecord [Single Table Inheritance](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance). The `type` attribute is by default used for that purpose, so it is automatically set.